# How do I get a string representation of a Parse Object ID?

Tags: parse-platform

How do I get a string representation of an object's ID?

```
let objectID = myObject.objectId as String


(lldb) po myObject.objectId
"ET1rEsXNHL"
 {
  _core = {
    _baseAddress = 0x00007f8132207e91
    _countAndFlags = 4611686018427387914
    _owner = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x00007f8132207e80 -> 0x000000010febc4b8 (void *)0x000000010febc468: __NSCFString)
  }
}
```

However I get a nil for the 'objectID' constant:

```
(lldb) po objectID
""
```

---

Here's a code snippet per request:

```
func retrieveAllMediaFromParse() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        let myData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: kParseMedia)
        myData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
            let NoErrors = !(error != nil)
            if (NoErrors) {
                // •Ric  -- for loop ---
                //  for object in objects {

                let myObject = objects[0] as PFObject
                let format = myObject.objectForKey("format") as String
                let access = myObject.objectForKey("access") as String
                let owner = myObject.objectForKey("owner") as String
                let memo  = myObject.objectForKey("text")! as? String
              //  let objectID = myObject.objectId as String

                let objectID = "ET1rEsXNHL"  // •Ric

                myMedia = gMedia(parseID: objectID, owner:owner, format:format, memo:memo!)
 ...
...
```

Comment: can you post your full code

Comment: I've added some code per request.

Comment: Actually, the objectId property is a string itself, so without casting it should show you  the string representation of the objectId. There must be some other problem here.

Comment: Agree with @DánielNagy.